# Determine convergence from experimental data set

Tags: statistics, experimental-mathematics

I have ran a simulation to get a set of data points represented in the image below:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKb39.png)

The $x$ values range from 5 to 400 in units of 1 (discrete x axis).

It is clear from the grapical representation that dependent value decreases as $x$ increases. Can anyone suggest how can I test if the data converges to any number greater than 0? All I can be certain of is that at infinity it is greater or equal to 0 (from the nature of the experiment it can only get positive values) .

Comment: looking at the graph it seems it may converge for some value $0.12\ge c\gt 0$ . You could find some more data points at a higher value if possible or try to add more constraints to get it to converge faster.

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the simulation algorithm, not necessarily in the real world. Can you share how these 'datapoints' were simulated?

Comment: @pranavB23 The problem is that it takes me around a week of the program running to get single data points of x values higher than 10000 or so.

Comment: Perhaps as BruceET said you could share the algorithm you used to generate these points.